# Change an error message, returned by SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I would like to change an error message returned by SharePoint 2007

"An error occurred copying some or all of the selected files"

So that it is more informative to end users.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this error message is actually generated by SharePoint. SharePoint is simply displaying the error that it encountered from another system component. I don't think you'll have much chance of changing it without doing crazy stuff.

Out of curiosity, how informative were you going to be? Compared to some of the generic errors that SharePoint returns, the one you're looking at isn't that bad.  :)

Comment: I was going to specify the allowed characters, and size limit of the file... Otherwise users just think the system isn't working properly and stop using it.

Comment: Are you getting this when coping files using explorer view? It looks like a webdav error. I understand what you're trying to achieve. I just don't think you'll be able to do it. Your other option is to do your best to educate users about the requirements before they hit this error.